# Finding out harmonic means based on two matrices and store results in third matrix

Tags: r, psych

I have two matrices a and b

```
a = matrix(1:4,ncol=2)
b = matrix(5:8,ncol=2)
```

Now i want to find out harmonic means of these and put in a third matrix.

An example :-

```
 x = a[1,1],y = b[1,1] then harmonic mean of x and y = 2*x*y/(x+y)
```

Desired Output:-

```
c = matrix(c(1.666667,4.2,3,5.333333),ncol = 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since arithmetic operators work elementwise on matrices should be:

```
2*x*y/(x+y)
```

.. or the obvious substitution.

Comment: Thank you Sir, you point out correct approach . I was using for loops to achieve that but its now working element wise

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just sub a and b into your equation:

```
 c <- 2*a*b/(a+b)
```

Output

```
         [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 1.666667 4.200000
[2,] 3.000000 5.333333
```